# need help making a website available for the public

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, web-services, hosting

So I recently took a remote internship with a company and my job is to re vamp the website. My supervisor gave me the websites WordPress login and password information. Me having no experience with WordPress i decided not to do it that way. Instead I hard coded everything on visual studio code. That way I could customize everything to my liking. Now I have this beautiful website but I am having trouble making it public.

I've set up an AWS server before and I've been able to put up my own websites with no domain name just using the servers ip.

So my question is would I need to ask the company what hosting service they use and Filezilla into the server so I can add my file containing the website? Or is there a way I can do this all on WordPress?

Comment: Did you create a new wordpress theme, or just "normal" webpage? If it's the second one, you won't be able to integrate it in any useful way with wordpress, you will indeed need access for their hosting to deploy your website.

Comment: I created html files using visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

If you built a new site from scratch using HTML, CSS and Javascript without building a Wordpress theme then it will not be possible to host it using a Wordpress host.

Your best bet is to ask your employer to check if their host is a VPS or a Wordpress managed solution.

If it's the former, simply remove Wordpress from the VPS and serve the site using Nginx.

If it is a managed Wordpress hosting solution, they will need to purchase or utilise another service.

Comment: thank you this is very helpful. What exactly does VPS mean?

Comment: A VPS is a Virtual Private Server. When you made a server in AWS and if you used ec2, this would've been a VPS. In short, make sure to ask your employer. They will likely have a better understanding of where to upload it than you do.

Comment: If this answer helped answer your question, make sure to mark it as accepted :) Best of luck